# PHP: getting user's IP address using lighttpd

Tags: php, ip, lighttpd

I tried this function but this always return the host/website's IP address instead of the user's IP
any idea why and how to fix it?

the website is not hosted on localhost and I'm using lighttpd to host the website

```php
<?php

function getUserIpAddr(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip = getUserIpAddr();
echo $ip;

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like the host has a reverse proxy in place so all the requests come from it. Nothing you can do about that short of changing the way the reverse proxy works (and by the sound of it, that is something you need to ask your hosting service to do) to set one of the forwarding headers you are looking for.

Comment: Or as if they are already passing it in a server variable, which you can also check yourself by dumping/logging `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Quentin the website is hosted on my linux machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lighttpd provides the remote address in the CGI environment variable `REMOTE_ADDR`.

lighttpd does not set `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` unless the request provides `Client-IP` header.  lighttpd does not set `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` unless the request provides `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Among the headers you are using, only `REMOTE_ADDR` is trustable.  You should never trust data controlled by the client.  If your setup has intermediate proxies which set headers such as `X-Forwarded-For`, and you trust the intermediate proxies, AND your server can not be reached by anything other than trusted proxies, then those headers can be trusted, too.

If your setup is behind a trusted proxy and you want to use `X-Forwarded-For`, then see lighttpd [mod_extforward](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModExtForward), which can parse `X-Forwarded-For` or standardized headers such as `Forwarded`, to put the upstream remote address into `REMOTE_ADDR` for you.  lighttpd mod_extforward also supports the HAProxy `PROXY` protocol.

Comment: Thank's for explaining everything

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
$ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
echo $ipaddress;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// Print IP of user
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = htmlentities($ip, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo"$ip";

// You can also get the users hostname
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$hostname = htmlentities($hostname, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo"$hostname";
?>
```

Comment: The OP is already looking at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and it doesn't give the result they want.